# How can I share or upload a image on Google+ without using intents.?

Tags: java, android, google-plus

I want to share "status" or "status with image"  to Google+ in my (Wall)Streams.It does work fine when i use intents.but i do not want to use it.i want use API same as Facebook.Can any one help to me to give any idea.is it possible??.

Comment: First hit on google: https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot post directly to a user's stream with the Google+ APIs. The intents approach to launch the share dialog is the preferred approach.

You can use the [moments.insert](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments/insert) to write app activities to the user's account, where they can choose whether or not to share them.